# How to solve this Conditional Probability?

Tags: probability

I'm studying here and I came across a conditional Probability problem and I have a hard time and I'm having a hard time with it.

Problem:

A group of Student were asked if they carried an ATM cards. If a student is selected at random, find the probability that he or she owns an ATM card given that the student is a freshman. Round your answer to three decimal places.

ATM Card Carrier:

freshman: 39
Sophomore: 18
Total: 57

Non-ATM card Carrier:

freshman: 21 sophomore:22 Total:43

Overall Total:

freshman total 60
sophomore total 40
Total 100

I know I'm suppose to use the Formula (P(A) and P(B)) / P(A)
However I don't understand how its suppose to be setup?
Could Someone land me their expertise.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

So, you know that $P(T) = 60/100$ of the students are freshmen. Then, only $P(A) = 39/60$ are atm card carriers. You want the probability of picking a freshman that carries a card. So, $P(T) * P(A) = P(A+T)$ gives the probability of the person being both a freshman and a card carrier.

Comment: Uhmm, ok so the total number of student is 60? ok now I don understand how exactly you got 39/60 and why? could could utilize layman's terms? I'm sorry for not understanding it.

Comment: @victor Unless I'm missing something, it is 60 because that is total number of freshman. chance of it being a freshman firstly is 60/100 then multiply with chance of that freshman having a card 39/60

Comment: Ahh I see, It's rather simple, ok thank again for explaining it, thanks @Joe

Comment: @VictorMartins It is not so.  $P(T)\cdot P(A)=P(A\cap T)$  is *only* true if the events are independent; which they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the event of ATM Card-carrier, and $B$ that of being a Freshman.

We have been given that: $~\mathsf P(A\cap B)= \dfrac{39}{(57+43)}~$ and that: $~\mathsf P(B)=\dfrac{57}{(57+43)}~$.

Because we have $39$ Freshmen carrying cards, $57$ Freshmen in total, and $43$ Seniors with other details irrelevant to this problem.

Then by definition of conditional probability and cancelling common factors in the division: $$\require{cancel}\mathsf P(A\mid B) ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(A)} ~=~ \dfrac{\cancelto{13}{39}\color{silver}{~/\cancel{(57+43)}}}{\cancelto{19}{57}\color{silver}{~/\cancel{(57+43)}}}~=~\dfrac {13}{19}$$

That is all.